# IllegalArgumentException in Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper() while using .createMock with EasyMock

Tags: java, junit, mocking, easymock, cglib

I encounter a problem during unit testing with EasyMock. When trying to create a mock object, the following Exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class  ...UnitOfWork$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$3561f3ca is not an enhanced class
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:621)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setThreadCallbacks(Enhancer.java:612)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.registerCallbacks(Enhancer.java:581)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory.createProxy(ClassProxyFactory.java:194)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:60)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.createMock(EasyMock.java:104)
    at testplugin.Test.testMethod(Test.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.s
```

What makes a class enhanced? And what is the Enhancer doing anyways (I don't know what `net.sf.cglib.proxy`package is about) And why is it not working for this class, but for another mock object directly created before this object?

```
Mock1 mock1 = EasyMock.createMock(Mock1.class);
UnitOfWork mockUow = EasyMock.createMock(UnitOfWork.class); // Exception Happening here
```

Used versions are `easymock-3.0.jar` and `cglib-nodep-2.2.jar`. 
`UnitOfWork` is not a final class. The only thing that might be different are transient fields. Sadly I can't provide the code or recreate the Exception with another class.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely strange. Cglib is used by EasyMock to create mocks under the hood. Which version of EasyMock and Cglib are you using?

Normally, when cglib creates a class, it adds some specific static fields to it. In your case, these fields were not found. But I can't think why the fields are not there in your case. Is the `UnitOfWork` class final?

Can you provide the `UnitOfWork` code? Or a subset reproducing the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited the question to give the information you asked for.

Comment: The first step I would suggest is to update to EasyMock 3.4 and see if it works. Then, without a way to reproduce, it will be hard to say.